# Independence of a linear and a quadratic form

Tags: self-study, independence, proof, quadratic-form

How can I prove the following lemma?

Let $\mathbf{X}^ \prime$ = $ \left[ X_1 , X_2 , \ldots, X_n \right]$ where $ X_1, X_2, \ldots X_n $ are observations of a random sample from a distribution which is $N \left ( 0,\sigma^2 \right)$. Then let $\mathbf{b}^\prime = \left[b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n \right]$ be a real nonzero vector and let $\mathbf{A}$ be a real symmetric matrix of order $n$. Then $\mathbf{b ^\prime X}$ and $ \mathbf{X} ^\prime \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} $ are independent **iff** $\mathbf{b} ^\prime \mathbf{A}=0.$

---

I know that $\mathbf{b^ \prime X } \sim N(0, \sigma^2 \mathbf{ b^\prime b})$ but I do not see how I could proceed here. My main difficulty lies on the fact that these two variables are very different; had it been two quadratic forms instead, then Craig's theorem would be of use.

Any advice?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you solve this problem under the more restrictive assumption that $b=(1,0,\ldots,0)^\prime$?  If so, you are done because the general one reduces to this upon choosing a suitable rotation of the coordinates and rescaling $b$.

Comment: @whuber Okay thank you. Then I can do one direction but if we assume that these two are independent how can I show that $ \mathbf{b \prime A}=0?$

Comment: You might try demonstrating the contrapositive: if $b^\prime A \ne 0,$ can you show that $b^\prime X$ and $X^\prime A X$ are not independent? I believe that examining the situation when $n=2$ will show the way.

Comment: @whuber I am quite stuck here I fear. My book takes that lemma for granted but I find it very counter-intuitive. Can the lemma be proved under the original assumption of the nonzero vector $\mathbf{b\prime}$?

Comment: @whuber I was thinking, can I use the fact that these two are uncorrelated as proof of independence? I mean I know this is both necessary and sufficient in case both variables are normally distributed but does it hold for my case?

Comment: No, because $X^\prime A X$ does not have a Normal distribution.  You might consider finding a square root of $A$, so that $X^\prime A X = X^\prime U^\prime U X,$ and use your idea to show that $b^\prime X$ and $U X$ have a joint Normal distribution and are uncorrelated.

Comment: I cannot comment yet with this account, but I like to add that $X'X$ is Wishart-distributed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution

Comment: Well $\mathbf{X} \prime \mathbf{X}/\sigma^2$ is $\chi^2 (n)$. It remains to prove the independence though.

Comment: Compute the joint mgf and check the condition for independence it’s brutal but effective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Craig's Theorem.  Consider the quadratic form on **b**.  If two random variables are independent, then any univariate functions of those random variables are likewise independent.  The quadratic forms are independent, ergo the linear form on **b** and the quadratic form on **A** are likewise independent.

Comment: Could you explain what the "quadratic form on $b$" is?  (In the question, $b$ is only the coefficient of a *linear* form $b^\prime X$.)  And what criterion are you using to determine that this form and the form $X^\prime A X$ are independent?

Comment: @Downvoter You did not even give Dennis the chance to clarify. He may be right.

Comment: Piece of crap commenting system.   The above should read:  $y = X'b'bX$ is a quadratic form, call it $X'BX$.  If $B'\Sigma A = 0$, the forms are independent.  Note that $A$ is at most rank $n-1$ (it could be smaller).  That establishes the the first half.  Next, suppose the forms are independent.  Apply the spectral decomposition theorem to $A$ and follow the consequences of the linear forms being independent.  I did inadvertently toss in an enthymeme that A was non-negative definite.  Cochran's theorem doesn't apply here, because A isn't necessarily nnd.

Comment: How do we know that the rank of $\mathbf{A}$ is at most $n-1$ or that it is positive semi-definite? I understand the application of Craig's theorem in the first part but could you please explain how the other direction follows from the spectral decomposition of $\mathbf{A}$? Thank you.

Comment: I neither see the proof by Craig's theorem, writing $A$ as $b'b$ is a nice decomposition but I see no connection on the independence between the quadratic and linear form.

Comment: @ John.  If $b'A = 0$ then that linear combination of the rows of A is 0, and so the vectors are not linearly independent.  $A$ cannot have rank greater than $n-1$ in that case.  $A$ is not necessarily nnd -- I added that assumption tacitly in my original response.

Comment: @ emcor:  If $X$ and $Y$ are stochastically independent, then for any functions $g(\cdot)$ and $h(\cdot)$, $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ are also independent.  Let $g(X) = b'X$ and $h(X) = X'A'X$. If you have shown that $g^2(X)$ is independent of $h(X)$, then $g(X)$ is also independent of $h(X)$.  We know in the case of Normal random variables that 0 covariance iff independence.  So if the linear and quadratic forms are independent, their covariance must be 0.  The covariance being zero (through the spectral decomposition of $A$) then leads to the condition $b'\Sigma A = 0$.

Comment: That answers my question, thank you. I'd be grateful though if you could also show how the covariance being zero implies that $b \prime \Sigma \mathbf{A} =\sigma^2 I b \prime \mathbf{A}=0$. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the univariate case $X=X_1$, we find the correlation:

$\rho(bX,AX^2)=bA\rho(X,X^2)=bA\dfrac{\mathrm{Cov}(X,X^2)}{ \sigma_X \sigma_{X^2}} =bA\dfrac{E[(X-\mu_X)(X^2-\mu_{X^2})]}{ \sigma_X\sigma_{X^2}}$

With $\mu_x=0$, $\sigma_x=\sigma$, and for the expectation we know the distributions of $X$ and $X^2$ (Normal and Chi-Square).

1. We see that $bA\neq 0$ implies $\rho\neq0$, so they are not independent in this case.
2. Now look at the case $bA=0$, which means $b=A=0$, $(b=0,A\neq0)$ or $(b\neq0,A=0)$:
   In the first case here,  we have $bX=0=AX^2$ and two constants are generally independent. For the other two cases, we have aswell that a constant $(0)$ and any random variable are independent.

So $(bX,AX^2)$ are independent only in the case $bA=0$, otherwise we have $\rho\neq0$.

This univariate case is not directly extendable to the multivariate case though because $X'AX\neq AX'X$.

As shortcut in general, if you have some transformation $Y=T(X)$, it is hence directly dependent on $X$ (not independent) except if any of them is a constant which here requires $b'A=0$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. It seems like your solution depends on the claim that any two uncorrelated random variables connected through a Gaussian copula must therefore be independent, but that is not true. Concerning your Wishart comment: you are correct, but understanding the "$\sigma^2$" of the question to be a scalar (as is conventional), $X^\prime X$ thereby is a scalar random variable with a scaled chi-squared distribution. The multivariate framework may be illuminating, but repeatedly insisting on that point does not seem to help us get any closer to a solution.

Comment: I changed it to Chi-Square now, but it does not really matter as you can see in the new version we can take out $bA$ in the correlation and see it should equal zero if $\rho=0$. Note that $\rho(aX+b,Y)=a\rho(X,Y)$.

Comment: @whuber I extended it to the multivariate case now.

Comment: Before we address that claim further, could you explain in what sense $T$ is increasing? Assuming $X$ and $A$ are real numbers, there are no values of $A$ that would make $T$ an increasing real-valued function of a real variable in any neighborhood of $0$ (which appears relevant, since Normal variates can take on all real values).

Comment: @whuber You are correct, $T=X^2$ is not increasing below $0$. $\rho=0$ might still be valid solution but it is indeed based on the Gaussian assumption.

Comment: @whuber We can now definetely say from above, that X and Y are not independent if $b'A\neq0$, because then their correlation is nonzero (so some linear dependency). So the only remaining case is $b'A =0$ which might have to be further argued in more detail again that it would be independent.

Comment: That correct. And that's the crux of the problem. Ultimately this question comes down to a theorem of linear algebra: when $A=U^\prime U,$ $Ab=0$ if and only if $Ub=0$.

Comment: The idea is to reduce the problem to that of the independence of the mean and variance of normally distributed variables.  The variance can be expressed a quadratic form in a set of up to $n-1$ normal variates. By showing those are all orthogonal to the mean (that is, uncorrelated with it), then by virtue of properties of multinormal distributions they are independent of the mean. The result follows immediately.

Comment: Your solution appears to be invalid because you are assuming $A$ and $X$ commute, which they do not.

Comment: $A$ is an $n$ by $n$ *matrix* and $X$ is a column vector of $n$ components. For $n\gt 1$ you cannot replace $X^\prime A X$ by "$AX^2$": it doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15308/discussion-between-whuber-and-emcor).